Does cn1 support Android 14
I created an app using cn1 that has been on the Google Play Store for a while.
Recently I received a warning on Google Play Console:

Your app currently targets API level 33 and must target at least API level 34 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. App updates with these issues will be rejected. App must target Android 14 (API level 34) or higher.
Fix by Aug 31.

So I created a new version of my cn1 app, on August/08/2024, and uploaded on Google Play Console, but the result is the same warning. It seems that cn1 does not support Android 14 yet.
My question is: when will cn1 start to support Android 14 ? The deadline to update my app is August 31.

Yes. See https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3820 this is the API level not the device/OS. We have experimental support for the API level which will be switched to default before August 31st.
